# Calling a pure virtual function in a separate thread that is created from base-class constructor

Tags: c++

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

class Base {
protected:
    pthread_t receiverThreadID;
    Base() {
        pthread_create(&receiverThreadID,NULL,threadFunction,this);
    }
    ~Base() {

    }

    virtual void handleEvent() = 0;
    static void* threadFunction(void* arg) {
        while(true) {
            // This threads receives UDP via recvfrom(). The messages can come in randomly. I use sleep() to simulate a blocking wait
            sleep(1);
            ((Base*)arg)->handleEvent();
        }
        return 0;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
    virtual void handleEvent() {
        // Do something
        printf("hello\n");
    }

public:
    Derived() {}
    ~Derived() {}

};

int main() {
    Derived derived;

    sleep(10);
}
```

You are not supposed to call a pure virtual function from the constructor of a class, but is it ok to create a thread in the constructor, that in turn calls a pure virtual function? Is there any risk for a race condition? I did not get any runtime errors with the code above.

If it is not ok to code like I've done, how should you solve it?

Comment: You need some synchronization mechanism to guarantee that the constructor is done.  That's all that matters here, when the thread gets created is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

This can blow up if the `threadFunction()` calls `handleEvent()` before the constructor of `Derived` is done.

Why not place the `pthread_create` call in another function - say, `start()` - and call it once the object is constructed?

```
class Base {
protected:
    pthread_t receiverThreadID;
    Base() {}
    ~Base() {}

    void start() {
        pthread_create(&receiverThreadID,NULL,threadFunction,this);
    }

    ...
};
```

Comment: Could i call start() from the constructor of Derived?

Comment: @mbarnapam: No, [just don't do it](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/nevercall.html). Particularly, what if you inherit `Derived` and override `handleEvent` again?

Comment: You can call the start() in constructor of Derived, however note that the Derived version of the virtual function will be called (which might or might not be a problem, depending whether you derive further from Derived). I.e. calling of virtual functions in constructor is well defined, but you need to know what will happen (which might be a different thing than you could expect).

Answer (score 1):

If you call it in a thread or directly doesn't matter, you should not call the pure virtual function before Derived is fully constructed - and this happens after the construction of Base.

Your sleep is what makes this code running, but not safe.

If you want a safe version, i see 2 options:

1. Use mutexes or similar mechanisms to prevent the thread from calling the function before the constructor is done.
2. (And thats probably the better option): Start your thread in a function called after the constructor. You might want to utilize a factory-function here to make sure it is always called.

Answer (score 0):

It is wrong to call virtual function when the constructor is not completely executed.

As other suggested, please make sure to have another function that used this virtual function. And call this function once object is created. 
eg.

```
class Base{
    static void *create_thread(void * arg){
         pthread_create(&receiverThreadID,NULL,threadFunction,this);
    }   

};
// client call something like this.
Base * b = new Derived();
b->create_thread();
```

Hope this should solve the problem.